# How can I plot a 2D figure in MATLAB by "connecting the dots"?

Tags: graphing-functions, matlab

I'm an amateur at MATLAB and I know how to do the basic stuff such as plotting functions, writing M files, functions, for loops, etc but I've be tasked to do something I have never done before.

I have to draw this figure which resembles a Tree or Home (2D childs drawing), and I know all of its points: (6,1), (8,1), (6, 3) (8,3) makes the base of the house (and the diagonals are drawn too) and then the points (6,3), (7,4), (8,3) make the roof.

How do I connect the points in a way that it resembles what I'm looking at?

Thanks.

Comment: you have multiple options. What seems easier is to plot every dot (as vectors X and Y) and then plot every segment... if you need further help, i'll gladly provide the code.

Comment: This is what I  currently have: 
`clear all;
plot([6 8],[1 1]);
grid on;
axis([5 9 0 5]);
hold on;
plot([6 8],[3 3]);
plot([6 6], [1 3]);
plot([8 8], [1 3]);
plot([6 8], [3 1]);
plot([6 8], [1 3]);
plot([6 7], [3 4]);
plot([7 8], [4 3]);`

But I'm wondering if there's a faster way to do this

Comment: you can merge various of those segments, but it depends on which segments you want drawn... as an example, for the cailing, 

plot([6 7 8],[3 4 3]);

Answer (score 1):

```
points = [
   6 1
   8 1
   6 3
   8 3
   7 4];

sequence = [1 2 4 3 1 4 2 3 5 4];
plot(points(sequence, 1), points(sequence, 2), '-o')
set(gca, 'XLim', [5, 9], 'YLim', [0, 5],'DataAspectRatio', [1 1 1])
figure(gcf)
```

Perhaps more idiomatically:

```
points = [
   6 1
   8 1
   6 3
   8 3
   7 4];

sequence = [1 2 4 3 1 4 2 3 5 4];
u = points(sequence, :);
plot(u(:, 1), u(:, 2), '-o')
set(gca, 'XLim', [5, 9], 'YLim', [0, 5],'DataAspectRatio', [1 1 1])
figure(gcf)
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help! Is there a way to group/treat the figure as one variable?

In case I need to rotate the whole thing about a certain point (and angle), I know the matlab "rotate" function exists

Comment: If you rotate the points, writing, say, `c = cos(pi/4); s = sin(pi/4); points = [c -s; s c] * points`, then the figure will rotate by $\pi/4$. Just do this before you compute `u`.